# How to catch error in nodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I have code like this:

```
try {
    var client = new Steam.SteamClient();

    client.logOn(credentials);
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
}
```

But still cant catch the error:

```
MacBook-Pro:steam $ node test.js
\events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: Logon fail: 63
    at SteamClient.handlers.(anonymous function) (/Users/Sites/steam/node_modules/steam/lib/handlers/user.js:178:11)
    at SteamClient._netMsgReceived (/Users/Sites/steam/node_modules/steam/lib/steam_client.js:106:26)
    at SteamClient.handlers.(anonymous function) (/Users/Sites/steam/node_modules/steam/lib/steam_client.js:192:10)
    at SteamClient._netMsgReceived (/Users/Sites/steam/node_modules/steam/lib/steam_client.js:106:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Connection._readPacket (/Users/Sites/steam/node_modules/steam/lib/connection.js:50:8)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:424:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:418:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:174:11)
```

The problems is that I have a list of acc and need to auth only those, which are ok. But on this error program closes.

Answer (score 2):

Error are passed through events for the Steam client, not through exceptions.

Try this:

```
var client = new Steam.SteamClient();

client.logOn(credentials);
client.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error('An error happened!');
  console.error(err);
});
```

More [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/steam#error).